# Paypal Website Payments Pro Iframe - pay with paypal button is redirecting to paypal

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, paypal

I have a problem with the paypal checkout iframe:

in the user guide of Website Payments 
Pro (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf) at page 47 says: "the buyer never leaves your website"

but the pay with paypal button is redirecting the user to paypal for the log in therefore is leaving the website.

The code I used is the same of the guide:

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>

<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" 
method="post" 
action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/
webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="MERCHANT ID">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
<input type="hidden" name="return" 
value="https://yourwebsite.com/receipt_page.html">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.form_iframe.submit();
</script>
```

does anyone had the same problem?

How can I solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying that the code reloads your entire page, and doesn't just show the PayPal login in the `<iframe>`?

Comment: It does nor reload the page but is redirecting the user to paypal for the login, the user should stay in the same page rather than be redirected, does it make sense?

Comment: The paypal login should show up inside the `<iframe>`; whatever else that appears on your page should still be there. It has to go to PayPal for the actual authentication; that's how PayPal works on every site I've ever seen it (except ebay, but then PayPal is part of ebay).

Comment: Right, but why in the documentation it says :"the buyer never leaves your website"? (Please see the link I wrote in the original post)

Comment: Well I guess it depends on what you mean by "leaves" :)  Your website is still there on the screen surrounding the `<iframe>`, so in some sense the user doesn't "leave" your content, but it is true that the user does have to directly interact with PayPal to authenticate and authorize the payment.

Comment: This looks the same as you're trying to do : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

Comment: If the user is redirected to paypal is "leaving" the website that's what I wanted to avoid, but if the redirection to paypal for the log in is required I'll drop the iframe and use something else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matteo, did you try using lightbox or something else to make it work? Ideally, this iframe code should be inside a modal dialog which would show up when the user clicks on a buy/pay/shop button.

Comment: No I did not try any lightbox, there is a lightbox integration offered by paypal but is different from the iframe of website pro, I'll use another way, thanks for your answer!